# How to get device id in Ionic 2 using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, phonegap-plugins, ionic2

I am trying to get device id in ionic2 using typescript.

I installed **cordova-plugin-device**

And my code is....

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
   console.log(device.cordova);
}
```

But this is not working.

When I launch the app on device, there is no any log.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a solution that has worked yet? I have imported as per documentation and trying to `console.log(Device.device.uuid)` like in docs but undefined.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like this is in the [Ionic 2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/device/). What you need to do is import the `Device` class from `ionic-native` and call the `uuid` property of the `device` object.

**For example**

```
import {Device} from 'ionic-native';

platform.ready().then(() => {
   console.log(Device.device.uuid);
}
```

Comment: Does it work for you then? notice my example accesses the id using `Device.device.uuid` and in your question you have written `device.cordova` which probably won't do anything as you aren't calling the `Device` class first. Plus if did write it properly, e.g. `Device.device.cordova`, it will return the version of Cordova on the device and not the device's unique id

Comment: This always gives me `undefined`.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal it used to work, but now it doesn't.

Comment: Device.uuid works for me only when the phone is connected to the computer via USB. Otherwise it is undefined.